# Creating analyzed and not_analyzed index on all fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, indexing, elasticsearch, mapping

Im pretty new to Elasticsearch. I have a requirement of creating ALL string fields with an "analyzed" and "not_analyzed" index. I have been able to do it for 1 or 2 fields, but how can I do this if I have 50 fields in my document? I have used the following code to create such an index on a few fields:

```
mapping = {
    "my_type": {
        "properties": {
            "random_num": {"type": "string"},
            "category": { "type":"multi_field", "fields":{ "category":{ "type":"string", "index":"analyzed" },"untouched":{ "type":"string", "index":"not_analyzed" } } },
            "url": {"type": "string"},
            "id": {"type": "string"},
            "desc": { "type":"multi_field", "fields":{ "desc":{ "type":"string", "index":"analyzed" },"untouched":{ "type":"string", "index":"not_analyzed" } } }
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate it if some one could help me out with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the document [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/custom-dynamic-mapping.html).
Using dynamic index templates , you can add rules like below and achienve the same.
In the following example , I have enabled an additional field called raw ONLY if the size is less than 256 which would be not_analyzed.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            },
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match": "*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```